# Statistics graph using bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have just begun studying this programming language, I need some help to create a graph using the information from a Script I wrote. Basically what the script does is it pings 8.8.8.8 and if it is successful it populates a log file with an UP and the time of the ping. I have a case in which when the user uses the option "C" it show the percentage of success for that hour and if the success rate is 10% i get 1 "*" if 20% i get 2 "**"

Comment: No i am afraid i am really terrible in this subject :S is there a way I can contact you privately to show you what I have done till now ?

Comment: That's not the purpose of this platform. Post your script here publicly, so that others facing similar issues can look it up later.

Comment: well ok than , the script i am using is this:

Comment: #!/bin/bash
time=$(date +"%H,%M,")
ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1;
if [[ $? = 0 ]]
then echo $time"UP" >> ~/logfile.log
else echo $time"Down" >> ~/logfile.log

now I need to take the inputs of logfile.log per hour and do a graph of what % of the pings where sucessfull

Comment: The output i need should be something like this:

Hour    % Success | Graph
0          10              | *
1          100            | **********

Comment: How about editing the question and paste the script formatted as source code? That would make reading it much easier.
The building block to print the status bar I already posted. Use `grep -c 'UP' logfile.log` to find out the number of successful tries, use `grep -c '^' logfile.log` to find out the number of total tries.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to output the progress bar. The number is rounded down, so 27/100=27% will be interpreted as 2 out of 10. The rest of the output you can figure out on your own, I think.

```
maxstars=10

tries=`grep -c '^' logfile.log`
success=`grep -c 'UP' logfile.log`
stars=`echo "$maxstars * $success / $tries" | bc`
for i in `seq 1 $stars`
do
    echo -n '*'
done
echo # just prints a newline
```